# Why doesn't os.system('set foo=bar') work?

Tags: python, environment-variables, environment

Possibly a stupid question: Why can't I set an environment variable with this?

```
os.system('set foo=bar') # on windows
```

I'm aware of `os.environ`, and that works for me. I'm just confused about why the former doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux) -- `export` and `set` are both shell commands, and whether on Windows or Unix, they're still inevitably being addressed to a **child process** running the shell (be it bash, cmd.exe, whatever) and so bereft of any further action when that child process terminates (i.e., when `os.system` returns to the caller).