# Setting environments variables from a python script

Tags: java, python, environment-variables, csh

I am using c-shell and I am used to using setenv. I need to execute an equivalent command from within a python script. I tried using os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/usr/local/java" which works from the python interpreter, but when my script is executed from the command line, the shell it ran in does reflect the newly set environment variable. Can anybody help, I am new to scripting, I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constuctor), it should be enough to pass the `env` parameter to the constructor to whatever you need as a dictionary (you can copy the contents of `os.environ` and add your own environment variables if you wish).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [How to use export with Python on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux), setting an environment variable within any process (such as your Python script) cannot affect any parent processes (such as the csh process from which you execute the Python script).

What you can do is have your Python script print a `setenv` command, and then evaluate the output in your shell as a command.

For example:

```
csh% cat foo.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os;

os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/local/java"

print "setenv JAVA_HOME", os.environ["JAVA_HOME"]
csh% ./foo.py
setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/local/java
csh% echo $JAVA_HOME 
JAVA_HOME: Undefined variable.
csh% eval `./foo.py` 
csh% echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/local/java
csh%
```

And you can set up an alias in your `~/.cshrc` to do the `` eval `...` ``, or just invoke it directly from your `.cshrc` or `.login` (depending on just what you're trying to accomplish).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is been a while sins this issue, but I solved it a little different.
Maybe this ain't even the most beautiful solution, but it works.

I created a shell script called env.sh

```
#!/bin/tcsh
eval $*
```

Then in my python script called subprocess.

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["env.sh", "setenv", "DISPLAY", "remhost:0"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()
```

This works for me, don't forget to make the env.sh executable by executing "chmod +x env.sh"

Comment: Just funny that you actually call it `env.sh` and it's started with `#!/bin/tcsh`.