# how to save data via export in python program?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, bash

I want to automate a specific task, and I have a bash file that I want to read data from user arguments by running the script

```sh
bash my_script.sh /etc/??? path/dst
```

till now, I'm getting the data in my script by access to positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`) and variables, and that's fine.

But inside the script, I want to run a python program. So...

```sh
python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

the things is, I have to read the data via python and access the output in my_script.sh

There is a constraint that I shouldn't create a file on the system. So I wonder about using `export`, but export is volatile since it's storing the variable till that process is opened and when I get back to `my_script.sh`, there isn't any clue of that data also I have no privilege to write my variable, and it's data on `~/.bashrc`.

Also, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496946/setting-environments-variables-from-a-python-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux), but they don't work the way I wanted.

if you regard the way I'm doing it, is wrong, let me know, please.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your script can capture or otherwise parse the output of `test.py` as it writes to standard output.

Comment: The python app that I want to run inside the script is not dependent on the `script`.
Also in the `script`, I want to have access to data I processed in python app, as I said `export` can save any data for me but it's not accessible after the line of executed python app, I mean in the rest of the script I have no access to export variables.
Can I parse the standard output? How?

Comment: `output=$(python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3)`, then do what you want with `$output`. `export` only passes information from a parent to a child process, not the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `@chepner`s comment, the solution was using `$()` instead of using `export`.

As it's mentioned in comments :

> export only passes information from a parent to a child process, not the other direction.

So one of the **correct ways** to get an output from other application within your script is as follows:

```sh
output=$(python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3)
```