# Change directory in terminal using python

Tags: python, chdir

I'm writing a simple script to change the present working directory to some other directory. The following script works okay until the program terminates, after which I'm back to my home directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir("/home/name/projects/python")
    os.system("pwd")
    print 'dir changed'
```

Output is:

```
bash:~$ python chdir.py
/home/name/projects/python
dir changed
bash:~$ pwd
/home/name
```

I want the directory change to remain even after the program has exited. Any ideas how to do it?

**Edit**:
What I really want to do is this: I use this directory frequently and instead of doing `cd <path>` every time I open the terminal, I just write `./progname` and it changes the directory.

Comment: Why are you doing this in Python?

Comment: It's kind of a part of a bigger project.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do. Python is actually changing the dir inside its scripts scope, but not on your terminal's scope

Comment: @RafaelCardoso exactly! Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I guess you should use a more bash-focused script language

Comment: Does using 'source python chdir.py' solves the problem?

Comment: @HugoSadok nope, throws an error "cannot execute binary file".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want the directory change to remain even after the program has exited. 
You can end the python script with `os.system("/bin/bash")`, this will leave you in bash shell inside the new directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir("/home/name/projects/python")
    os.system("pwd")
    os.system("/bin/bash")
```

For the need raised in your comment "I use this directory frequently and instead of doind `cd <path>` every time I open the terminal, I just write `./progname` and it changes the directory"
I would suggest using bash alias which will change directory:

```
bash:~$ alias mycd='cd /home/name/projects/python'
```

and use this alias in bash shell in order to change the directory:

```
bash:~$ mycd
```

You can add this alias to your `.bashrc` - which will allow you to use this alias every time.

Comment: This works!
Thank you very much. Can you explain me what the last command is doing? Is it creating a new instance of terminal or what?

Comment: It opens a new bash shell as a sub-process, hence it uses the new directory. It answers you questions, but I'm not sure how useful will it be for a large scale project. For more info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux.

Comment: I knew it could be done by using bash alias, i just wanted to know how to do it with python. Both of your solutions work. Thanks again!

Comment: Please note @KrishanuKonar that this is not actually changing your directory of your current bash session. It is creating a new bash process in the directory you want. What you are actually asking for is impossible with Python, but extremely easy with bash.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone would like to do this without python - this is most simply done with a `.bash_profile` file.

Steps:

1. Type this into your .bash_profile. You can open this file with pico.

```
pico ~/.bash_profile
```

2. Then create a shortcut (called an alias), you can do whatever phrase you want.

```
alias cdd="cd ~/frequent/my-directory"
```

3. Then source your `.bash_profile` file.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now, you just run your aforementioned shortcut, and this switches your directory, with many less key strokes!

```
Macbook-Spen:~ spen$ cdd
Macbook-Spen:my-directory spen$
```

---

Sources:

- https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/create-aliases-in-bash-profile-to-assign-shortcuts-for-common-terminal-commands/
- [How do I edit $PATH (.bash_profile) on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx)

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
os.system('cd /home/name/projects/python')
```

Comment: why you want to do it?
if you want to run another command on projects/python directory 
it will after this os.system('cd /home/name/projects/python')
You can use os.system('Another command')

Comment: its a small part of a bigger project.

Comment: I know it'll work after that, I need to preserve the directory change after the program has exited. Think of it like this: I use this directory frequently and instead of doind cd <path> everytime i open the terminal, i just write ./progname and it changes the directory.