# How can I execute an os/shell command from python

Tags: python

For say in terminal I did `cd Desktop` you should know it moves you to that directory, but how do I do that in python but with use Desktop with `raw_input("")` to pick my command?

Comment: Are you asking how to perform shell/cmd commands via raw_input in Python?

Comment: chuck logan that is correct thank you for knowing understanding my question

Comment: Chuck Logan i checked it out there is no sign of raw_input as i see

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? `raw_input` from python 2 is now `input` in python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code reads your command using raw_input, and execute it using os.system()

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        exec_cmd = raw_input("enter your command:")
        os.system(exec_cmd)
```

Best Regards,
Yaron

Comment: When using the code cd wont work

Comment: See the following Q&A which deals with "cd" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843054/change-directory-in-terminal-using-python/35843532#35843532

Comment: When i open the file and do cd /home/pi/Desktop/asf1/dos nothing happens

Comment: As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843054/change-directory-in-terminal-using-python/35843532#35843532 - when executing this code, with "cd /home" - the directory is changed while python is running. After python process ends, you receive the original shell with the original current-directory.

Comment: Sorry about this but how would i make it not end?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Did you read the entire Q&As here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843054/change-directory-in-terminal-using-python/35843532#35843532

Comment: So in the code you sent me after one command the process ends

Comment: The code in the accepted answer in Yaron's link launches a new bash process in the new directory so that when the Python script ends you are still in the new directory. If you end that process with ^D (or `exit`) you will be returned to the previous bash process.

Comment: How do i stop the script from ending after a command is executed?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> input = raw_input("") 
>>> suprocess.call(input.split()) # for detail usage, search subprocess
```

for details, you can search `subprocess` module

Comment: This will throw an error in the case of `input = "ls -l"` as shown in the `subprocess` docs. You need to `split` the input string by the `space` character in order to give `subprocess.call()` something it can work with (a list).

Comment: @skeletalbassman, yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To go with your specific example, you'd do the following:

```
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory = raw_input("Please enter absolute path: ")
    old_dir = os.getcwd() #in case you need your old directory
    os.chdir(directory)
```

I've used this technique before in some directory maintenance functions I've written and it works. If you want to run shell commands more generally you'd something like:

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == "__main__":
    command_list = raw_input("").split(" ")
    ret = subprocess(command_list)
    #from here you can check ret if you need to
```

But beware with this method. The system here has no knowledge about whether it's passing a valid command, so it's likely to fail and miss exceptions. A better version might look like:

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == "__main__":
    command_kb = {
        "cd": True,
        "ls": True
        #etc etc
    }
    command_list = raw_input("").split(" ")
    command = command_list[0]
    if command in command_kb:
        #do some stuff here to the input depending on the
        #function being called
        pass
    else:
        print "Command not supported"
        return -1
    ret = subprocess(command_list)
    #from here you can check ret if you need to
```

This method represents a list of supported commands. You can then manipulate the list of args as needed to verify it's a valid command. For instance, you can check if the directory you're about to `cd` exists and return an error to the user if not. Or you can check if the path name is valid, but only when joined by an absolute path.