# Make variable from Python file available on command line

Tags: python, shell

I have a small Python file from a third-party package with

```
$ cat a.py
a = 3.14
```

I would now like to make the value of `a` available on the command line. I initially thought that I just `grep`/`sed`/`awk` my way out of this, but perhaps there's a more pythonic approach.

Any hints?

Comment: You say it's third party but I don't understand why that stops you from adding code to it.

Comment: I have to fetch the source from upstream regularly and I need a clean source after reading the version. Perhaps one could programmatically insert code, execute, and remove the code again, but a little over-the-top.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple crude solution:

```
$ cat a.py
a = 3.14
a *= 2
$ python <(cat a.py && echo '\nprint(a)') 
6.28
```

There are various ways this might not work, but the constraints of your situation are not clear.

The `\n` is there to prevent a syntax error in the case that `a.py` does not end in a newline.