# How to use export with Python on Linux in Juypter Notebook

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code-server

I have a follow-up question to this topic: [How to use export with Python on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux)

In my case I am working on a visual studio code server. I understood so far, that it is not possible to change the enviornment variables in python. So for that I use my linus terminal with the command:

```
export INDEX=1
```

When I run the py.file in the workspace it works fine.

But if I try to use my interactive window, the error is:

> [2023-11-16 08:53:13.155242] [None] [ERROR] [None] int() argument must
> be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType

which is exactly the error I got in my py-run before I was setting the INDEX with export. How can I set the INDEX enviornment variable also for jupyter notebook?

Comment: If you want to set environment variables in Jupyter Notebook, you can use the %env magic command. In your case, you can do the following:

%env INDEX=1